# Is earning money by carrying other people's gold allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, trading

Nowadays, many people are trying to find shortcuts to earning money.

The Indian government has recently imposed a number of restrictions on the import of gold, but has exempted certain people who may carry up to 1 kg gold with them across the border by only paying the duty.  Many businesses, in order to get around these restrictions, elect to use individuals to carry gold for them one kilogram at a time, and pay them for their service.

In Islam, is it permissible for these people (the ones who carry the gold) to earn a profit in such a way?

Comment: I don't think this is haraam. And -- technically-speaking -- it is not illegal either. Having said that, even I await some good answers for this.

Comment: Yes, it is halal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed. Narrated Aisha:

> (the wife of the Prophet) Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and **Abu Bakr hired a
>   man from the tribe of Bani-Ad-Dil as an expert guide** who was a pagan
>   (follower of the religion of the pagans of Quraish). The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   and Abu Bakr gave him their two riding camels and took a promise from
>   him to bring their riding camels in the morning of the third day to
>   the Cave of Thaur.
>
> Reference  : Sahih al-Bukhari 2264

Answer (score 0):

According to Shia, each unlawful act is counted as an impermissible deed. (in other words it could be Haram) So, I assume you can compare this issue with the law, so if it is counted as a lawful act ( according to your country's laws), hence it would be a permissible act.